# Keep object alive during unmanaged asynchronous operation

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, .net-4.5, unmanaged

I'm working with an unmanaged function that takes a pointer to some unmanaged memory. The function returns immediately when called and asynchronously operates on the memory in the background. It takes an additional IntPtr that it passes back to my managed code when the operation completes. It's possible to have multiple such operations running at the same time.

I'm encapsulating the pointer to unmanaged memory in a custom SafeBuffer instance that I'd like to get back when an asynchronous operation completes. The SafeBuffer ensures that the memory gets properly released when there are no references to it. The problem is that the memory, of course, shouldn't be released while it's still in use by the unmanaged function.

How can I achieve this? The unmanaged function is called billions of times, so performance is critical.

I could allocate a GCHandle whenever I call the function, use it to get the SafeBuffer back when the operation completes, and free it. However, allocating handles seems to be expensive and performance decreases significantly over time.

I could allocate a GCHandle once, but then the unmanaged memory does not get released when the memory is not in use by the unmanaged function and there are no references to the SafeBuffer.

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you are getting called by unmanaged code on completion. How do you get access to the corresponding SafeBuffer in the completion callback at the moment? If you can get access to it it obviously has not been collected yet.

Comment: At the moment I'm doing what I describe in the question: I'm using a GCHandle that I pass to unmanaged code, get back and use to obtain the managed object.

Comment: Your question is missing a crucial word: "It takes an additional that it passes back to my managed code when the operation completes." - an additional what?

Comment: @JonSkeet: It's an additional IntPtr parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection:

```
public class SafeMemory : SafeBuffer
{
    private GCHandle referenceHandle;
    private SafeMemory[] reference;

    public SafeMemory()
    {
        this.reference = new SafeMemory[1];
        this.referenceHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(this.reference);
    }

    ~SafeMemory()
    {
        this.referenceHandle.Free();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        this.reference[0] = this;

        StartUnmanagedAsyncOperation(this, this.referenceHandle);
    }

    static void AsyncOperationCompleted(GCHandle referenceHandle)
    {
        ((SafeMemory[])referenceHandle.Target)[0] = null;
    }
}
```

<sup>(SafeBuffer implementation omitted for brevity.)</sup>

The user code creates and holds a reference to a SafeMemory instance. The SafeMemory instance and a GCHandle hold a reference to an 1-element SafeMemory array. The GCHandle is released when the user code no longer holds the reference to the SafeMemory instance.

While an unmanaged asynchronous operation is in progress, the array is made to hold a reference to the SafeMemory instance. This means the GCHandle holds a reference to the array and the array holds a reference to the SafeMemory instance, which prevents the GCHandle from being released even if the user code stops holding the reference to the SafeMemory instance.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a lookup-table on the managed side:

```
static ConcurrentDictionary<long, SafeBuffer> handles = new ...();
static long nextHandle = 0;

static long GetNextHandle(SafeBuffer buffer) {
    var handle = Interlocked.Increment(ref nextHandle);
    handles.Add(handle, buffer);
    return handle;
}
```

You call `GetNextHandle` before calling into unmanaged code. On completion you remove the handle from the `handles` dictionary.

A handle is just an arbitrary `long` that is stable (does not change) and can be passed to unmanaged code.

Comment: This is *much* better (10 million op/s) than allocating a GCHandle for each operation (0.6 million op/s and decreasing), but also *much* worse than allocating a GCHandle just once and getting the Target for each operation (174 million op/s on my machine).

Comment: You are saying that you can do FromIntPtr and get_Target 174m/sec/core? That sounds like a lot. Also measure creating the handle and destroying it.

Comment: 41 million op/s with ToIntPtr/FromIntPtr, 174 million op/s if I pass the GCHandle directly (it's an IntPtr-sized struct); not measuring the managed/unmanaged/managed transitions. Didn't try multiple cores yet.

Comment: I thought you have to create and destroy a GCHandle per call which means this should be included in the measurement (?). Or can you reuse GCHandles? In that case you could also reuse my "handles".

Comment: If I allocate and free a GCHandle per call, then the performance is horrible (around 0.6 million op/s in the first few seconds; gets much worse over time). I get the high numbers when I allocate the handle only once (and keep the managed object in memory forever).

Comment: Another idea: keep a pool of SafeBuffer's (a few hundred) and keep them pinned all the time. Store them in an array and pass the index to unmanaged memory. That way you are completely free vom GCHandle performance and also have no locking at all at runtime.

Comment: Manual memory management is certainly possible. It would just be... *nicer* if you hadn't to manage memory manually in a garbage-collected language :-)